# Where to put a piece of code in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a post controller that has many comments.
The post model has a field called has_comments which is a boolean (so I can quickly select from the database only posts that have comments).
To create a new comment for a post, I use the `create` action of my comments controller.

After I create the comment I need to update my post's has_comments field and set it to `true`.

I can update this field from the `create` action of my comments controller, but that doesn't seem right - I feel that I should really be using the post's `update` action, but I'm not sure if it's right to call it (via `send`?) from the create action of the comments controller.

Where should the code for updating the post be?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why clutter your database with another column when the interface is programmatic? Make has_comments a method on Post:

```
def has_comments
  comments.size > 0
end
```

Then implement a counter_cache as suggested to reduce the query load.

EDIT: Alternatively, after implementing a counter cache, you could use a named_scope on Post to retrieve all posts that have comments, using a single query, if that's the main goal:

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
end

class Post
  named_scope :with_comments, {:conditions=>"comments_count > 0"}
end
```

EDIT: You can also avoid the famous n+1 query problem by a judicious use of :include:

```
posts = Post.find(:all, :include => :comments)
```

Comment: This will also avoid inconsistencies (e.g. in the case of a deleted comment), which you'd have to consider otherwise

Comment: Agreed. Using a new column+callbacks is heavy and brittle for what should be a simple method.

Comment: then how would you go about selecting ALL posts that have a comment from the database without fetching all the posts, then counting the comments for each one, and then filtering the result? This is a lot more memory intensive than to simply change a value in a column. is it not?

Comment: If the main goal is to retrieve all posts with comments, then a named_scope probably makes more sense, something like I've added above.

Answer (score 1):

You could use before_save callback in your model.

Even better way would be to use built in :counter_cache option which automatically caches the number of comments for each post. (see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001835 under options for belongs_to)

Comment: thanks. which model would I put the before_save callback in? I don't think the parent (i.e. post model) get saved when a comment is created/updated. But putting code that updated the post (parent) inside the comment model isn't very appropriate, is it? What do I have the post controller's update method for, then?

Comment: You should put it in comments before_save. It's ok to update Post when new Comment is created. Basically the Rails is doing the same when you set :counter_cache for belongs_to (which is in Comment model).

Comment: Actually, `before_save` is not the correct callback. I would use after_save instead, and on the `Comment` model, as mentioned below. Because if something would go wrong at save-time, you have updated the `has_comments` field incorrectly. 
But, using the `:counter_cache` is a very good solution and will handle all the heavy work for you.

Comment: Counter cache is the most amazing solution... has it only worked. See my post about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955820/how-to-implement-a-counter-cache-in-rails

Answer (score 1):

use after_save in comment model

```
def after_save
  #this will set "has_comment" of the Specified Post to true if it's not true already
  self.post.update_attribute('has_comment', true) unless self.post.has_comment
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it appropriate to update a model's parent (the comment's post) through the child's model (comment model)? Why would I not send for the `update` method of the posts controller here?

Comment: No update method will update all the data with data which already saved in database and set has_comment =true.also update_attributes of update method call all the callbacks if set in Post model whereas update_attribute doesn't, so it's increase your execution time.